# Shared authentication across multiple django sites

Tags: django

I have 3 django sites and they are deployed in 3 subdomains let's say like this:

- a.example.com
- b.example.com
- c.example.com

They all have 95% things in similar just uses 3 different database and have user login. Problem is I need to login to all 3 of them, why can't I login to one and share it with other 2 sites? I tried using multiple database/routing as described in Django documentation but I cannot share User model across multiple database. So how does sites like google does it? I login to one of their services and all others automatically log me in. Can someone give me proper guideline how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fully depends on your auth implementation. If you use sessions it will be complicated, because sessions is stored in database, files on server, memory etc. So between different servers they can't be shared [How sessions works](https://machinesaredigging.com/2013/10/29/how-does-a-web-session-work/#:%7E:text=Structure%20of%20a%20session,-The%20session%20is&text=The%20session%20can%20be%20stored,and%20managed%20by%20the%20server.). You can share sessions, if you will have another auth server, to which other servers would make requests to. But better approach is not using sessions, but jwt tokens, [Learn more about jwt](https://jwt.io/) . JWT tokens is stored in user browser (usually local storage). And server could decode them and validate if your user is authenticated.